# nprogress-rails with turbolinks not working in rails 4.2.6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

i'm trying to use gem `nprogress-rails`: https://github.com/caarlos0/nprogress-rails with Turbolinks, but even requiring it in `application.js` and `application.css.scss` it doesn't load or work. There's no error in browser console and the javascript files `nprogress.js` and `nprogress-turbolinks` are loaded in every page refresh.

Here is my `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require nprogress
//= require nprogress-turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

And here is my `application.css.scss`:

```
 *= require nprogress
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

Lastly, my Gemfile includes the gem `nprogress-rails`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'nprogress-rails'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed 'data-turbolinks-track' => true in your view?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 
                                              'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```